# App crashes when attempting to swap activities

Tags: java, android

This is a basic activity swapping.

The app does not crash if i declare a local button inside the configureActivitySwap() method like this:

```
Button voiceBtn = (findViewById(R.id.goToVoice));
```

But I have to declare the button in the global scope instead so I can use the button in other methods, mainly activating and deactivating the button when it should/should not be pressed.

I also noticed that if I remove the `finish();` method and replace it with something else the app functions normally, but I have to have the `finish();` method one way or another.

```
public class RecogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button voiceBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        voiceBtn = findViewById(R.id.goToVoice);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        // some unrelated code

        configureActivitySwap();
    }

    public void configureActivitySwap(){
        // Button voiceBtn = (findViewById(R.id.goToVoice));

        voiceBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My runtime error logs:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: tk.gandriks.gaaudiotransform, PID: 23125
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tk.gandriks.gaaudiotransform/tk.gandriks.gaaudiotransform.RecogActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at tk.gandriks.gaaudiotransform.RecogActivity.configureActivitySwap(RecogActivity.java:140)
            at tk.gandriks.gaaudiotransform.RecogActivity.onCreate(RecogActivity.java:124)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Should you use StartActivity() method in your OnClick Callback method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the setContentView() before calling voiceBtn = findViewById(R.id.goToVoice); Since you don't specify the layout the findViewById method will not get the button instance

```
public class RecogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private Button voiceBtn;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // set the layout first
      setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_XML_FILE_NAME)

      voiceBtn = findViewById(R.id.goToVoice);

      // some unrelated code

      configureActivitySwap();
 }

 public void configureActivitySwap(){
    // Button voiceBtn = (findViewById(R.id.goToVoice));

    voiceBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, i made this thread in a rush and i accidentally mistook the `setContentView();` method for unrelated code and didn't mention it. I am already using it, this is not the issue. Here, i edited the code as it currently is, and the issue persists.

Comment: @Greg You must call `setContentView` before `voiceBtn = findViewById(R.id.goToVoice);`

Comment: Oh damn... I think i may be an idiot

Answer (score 1):

Try I guess) In your `// some unrelated code` is contains `setContentView` method?

```
public class RecogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button voiceBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        voiceBtn = findViewById(R.id.goToVoice);

        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)
        // some unrelated code

        configureActivitySwap();
    }

    public void configureActivitySwap(){
        // Button voiceBtn = (findViewById(R.id.goToVoice));

        voiceBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You caught NPE because of `findViewById` is calling on inflated view. You are have been calling `findViewById` before `setContentView` in the first case and got the exception. And in the second case - in `configureActivitySwap`, that going after `setContentView`. Move `setContentView` after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and all will be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting layout before trying to find view with findViewById?
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

Comment: Yes, i do. Pardon for forgetting to mention i am going to edit the code.

Answer (score -2):

```
voiceBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goToVoice);
```

replace the statement in your `onCreate()` method with the above. It should work.

and use

```
super.finish() instead of finish()
```

Comment: casting is no longer required in new android studio versions

Comment: It does it automatically, that's clearly not the problem!

Comment: This doesn't work. It is the same way to write it, the (Button) part is redundant.